# want to get current year In oracle dev6i forms

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
DECLARE
    thisyear number(4,0);
BEGIN
    thisyear := year(getdate());
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`EXTRACT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) function:

```
DECLARE
    thisyear number(4,0);
BEGIN
    thisyear := extract(year from sysdate);
END;
```

Alternatively, you can use `TO_CHAR` with format string:

```
DECLARE
    thisyear number(4,0);
BEGIN
    thisyear := to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'));
END;
```

Comment: This is working in SQLdevloper but got error in forms. "ENCOUNTERED THE SYMBOL "FROM" when expecting one of the following..()*@$%&....."

Comment: @Hussain - Added another method. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gurwinder